# How can I access an element in a datatype list of SML?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have two defined datatypes

```
datatype adj = V of int * int list;
datatype graph = G of adj list;
```

adj is the information of a vertex, int is the id and int list is the list adjacent vertex id

I am writing a function, *get_edges* that returns a list of all edges incident to a given vertex vi in the graph. The edges are in the form of (vi, vj), for all vj ∈ L, from the adjacency list V (vi, L). The order of edges is the same as the order of vj in L.

```
val get_edges = fn : int * graph -> (int * int) list
```

e.g.

```
get_edges(0, G [V(0, [1]), V(1, [0])]); 
val it = [(0,1)] : (int * int) list
```

However, I have no ideas of how to access the element inside the graph so that I can return the edge, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern matching is used to get at the parts of datatype.

You can write a pair of access functions:

```
fun node (V(i,_)) = i;
fun neighbors (V(_,nodes)) = nodes;
```

Then, for example:

```
- val a_list = V(0,[2,3,4,7]);
val a_list = V (0,[2,3,4,7]) : adj
-
- node a_list;
val it = 0 : int
-
- neighbors a_list;
val it = [2,3,4,7] : int list
```

In practice, there is seldom any need to write such access functions. Instead, you just directly use pattern matching in any function designed to work with your type.

To illustrate how this works in this case, we can define a helper function (which will be useful in your main function):

```
fun expand (V(i,[])) = []
|   expand (V(i, node::nodes)) = (i,node) :: expand (V(i,nodes));
```

`expand` has type `fn : adj -> (int * int) list`

For example:

```
- expand(V(0,[2,3,4,7]));
val it = [(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),(0,7)] : (int * int) list
```

Given such a function and the idea of pattern-matching, you should be able to implement `get_edges`

Comment: `fun get_edges(i,G[V(j,k)::tl]) = 
if i = j 
then expand(V(j,k))
else get_edges(i,G[tl]);

get_edges(2, G [ V(0, [1]), V(1, [0]), V(2, []) ] ) ;`

Thanks for your help, I am trying of writing the get_edges part from what I've understanded from yours, but I still can't run the code without error, is that I am still making mistakes?

Comment: Almost there: `fun get_edges(i,G(V(j,k)::tl)) = if i = j then expand(V(j,k)) else get_edges(i,G tl); ` (note the replacement of the first two square brackets by parenthesis and the deletion of the second two -- `(j,k)::tl)` and `tl` are already lists). You should probably throw in a clause to handle the pattern `get_edges(i, V [])` to handle isolated nodes in the graph.

Comment: I meant -- you should handle the case `get_edges (i, G [])` which corresponds to the case where `i` isn't in the graph. You could consider this an error and perhaps even leave as is, but I tend to like to write SML code so as to avoid a non-exhaustive matchings warning if at all possible.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Yeah, those "not exhaustive" warnings are immensely useful for knowing what code needs attention when extending a datatype with new constructors.

Comment: Great help~ Thanks a lot